# Calculating minimal detectable effect with 0 historic conversions

Tags: ab-testing

I'm new to conversion rate optimisation, I'm currently prioritising my test ideas based on the effort and impact.

Am I right in thinking that the MDE is the minimum uplift from baseline to be confident in the data?

Example:

- Current monthly conversions = 23
- Monthly traffic = 1000
- Duration of A/B Test = 4 weeks
- MDE = 54.78% (CXL tool)

This would mean if control got 16 conversions during the test, Variation A must get a minimum of 24 conversions to be statistically significant?

If this is correct, how would I measure this with current avg conversions being at 0 due to lack of tracking?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t really matter if you’ve got no historic data because of issues beforehand as whilst the test is running you should be getting conversion data from both A (the control) and B (the variant).

As long as your tracking is set up during the testing then you’ll be able to see which variant is the favourite

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my issue is calculating the MDE pre-test with no historic data. Am I misunderstanding MDE?